# sql + react выгрузка данных

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

У меня есть фронтэнд на реакте, и бекенд на node.js, в бекэнде панель админа которая изменяет данные в бд.

И мне нужно загрузить данные из бд в react, например:

```
var headerContent = getData from sql;
```

функция должна:

```
return (
  <header>{headerContent}</header>
)
```

не знаю как выгрузить данные из бд в реакт.